# Postfix - Mail not delivering except from root

Tags: email, sendmail, postfix-mta

When I try to send an email as root using the following command, the email delivers successfully:

```
echo "Test" | sendmail -r user@mydomain.com myemail@gmail.com
```

But when I send an email, using the same command, as a different user, it does not deliver the email even though it's successful in the logs.

Log as root:

```
Jun 16 11:28:53 mydomain postfix/pickup[2163]: 34AF541D1C: uid=0 from=<user@mydomain.com>
Jun 16 11:28:53 mydomain postfix/cleanup[3168]: 34AF541D1C: message-id=<20140616112853.34AF541D1C@mydomain.com>
Jun 16 11:28:53 mydomain postfix/qmgr[2164]: 34AF541D1C: from=<user@mydomain.com>, size=247, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 16 11:29:06 mydomain postfix/smtp[3170]: 34AF541D1C: to=<myemail@gmail.com>, relay=spmail-sms-gw.cloudmark.com[66.151.128.162]:25, delay=13, delays=0.03/0.01/7.2/6.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 EzUt1o001190bAS01zV09C mail accepted for delivery)
Jun 16 11:29:06 mydomain postfix/qmgr[2164]: 34AF541D1C: removed
```

Log as another user:

```
Jun 16 11:29:53 mydomain postfix/pickup[2163]: 34AF541D1C: uid=1000 from=<user@mydomain.com>
Jun 16 11:29:53 mydomain postfix/cleanup[3168]: 34AF541D1C: message-id=<20140616112953.34AF541D1C@mydomain.com>
Jun 16 11:29:53 mydomain postfix/qmgr[2164]: 34AF541D1C: from=<user@mydomain.com>, size=247, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 16 11:30:06 mydomain postfix/smtp[3170]: 34AF541D1C: to=<myemail@gmail.com>, relay=spmail-sms-gw.cloudmark.com[66.151.128.162]:25, delay=13, delays=0.03/0.01/7.2/6.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 EzUt1o0014340bAS01zV09C mail accepted for delivery)
Jun 16 11:30:06 mydomain postfix/qmgr[2164]: 34AF541D1C: removed
```

Comment: The remote MTA `spmail-sms-gw.cloudmark.com[66.151.128.162]` gave `250 2.0.0` and accepted the mail. It is it's responsibility to deliver the mail or bounce it to the sender, if it can't deliver it.

Comment: I understand. I just don't see any difference between the 2 emails except for the uid and different message ids.